# Dropdown Box With ENUM in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have a table in my database, one of it fields data type is `ENUM`
now i am working in Yii framework, and I want to make a dropdown box and the list that we want to use is the lists that contain in `ENUM`.

Example:

```
table x
field -> category -> ENUM(HARD,MEDIUM,EASY)
```

I want to make a dropdown box and the option is `HARD`, `MEDIUM`, and `EASY`

Comment: did you find what you've been looking for?

Answer (score 5):

make a function in your model to return an array of your list:

```
public function getOptions()
{
   return array(
      'EASY',
      'MEDIUM',
      'HARD',
   );
}
```

then you could use it like this:

```
echo $form->dropdownList($model , 'category' , $model->options); // this will use that function to get the array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use params for the same in Yii.

Ex: 
Define categoryValues under "params" array in config file.

```
'params' => array(
  'categoryValues'=>array(
      'EASY',
      'MEDIUM',
      'HARD'
  ),
),
```

Use :

```
echo $form->dropdownList($model , 'category' , Yii::app()->params['categoryValues']);
```